# Uncaught TypeError: Property 'handleEvent' is not callable

Tags: javascript, json, async-await, dom-events

I am trying to make my first web app (a tarot card drawer with meanings, interpretations and symbolism listed). It is based on this other project:

https://github.com/SamJamWillingham/Tarot-Card-Drawer

I am modifying it a bit by loading an external local JSON file instead of keeping a massive object in the JSt is very basic and I am a beginner, so I would appreciate some help.

No matter what I do I keep getting this error:

"Uncaught TypeError: Property 'handleEvent' is not callable"

Whenever I click on the the tarot cards, which should draw another card.

Here is the code:

```js
let carda = document.querySelector("div.carda");

let cardb = document.querySelector("div.cardb");
let cardName = document.querySelector("h3.name");
let moreInfo = document.querySelector("p.about");

async function drawCard(x) {
  const birchwood = 'tarotdeck.json';
  const request = new Request(birchwood);
  const response = await fetch(request);
  const cardsArr = await response.json();
  const attributesArr = Object.values(cardsArr.cards[x]);
  console.log(attributesArr)
  return attributesArr;
}

//Making the function syncronous doesn't help
function getRandomNumber(min, max) {
  let step1 = max - min + 1;
  let step2 = Math.random() * step1;
  let result = Math.floor(step2) + min;
  return result; //I refuse to rely on hoisting, its like autosave
}
const jackandjill = async() => {
    return eval((drawCard(getRandomNumber(0, 78))));

    async function changeCard(inputLetter) {
      let cardString = eval("card" + inputLetter);
      const card = cardString;
      const ranIndex = getRandomNumber(0, 78); //obviously this has to match the number of cards.
      const cardDrawn = await drawCard(ranIndex); //this too must be async, or else ITS ALWAYS undefined, but the console.log is good enough
      cardName.innerHTML = cardDrawn[0];
      moreInfo.innerHTML = cardDrawn[1];

      function fill(num, dommy) {
        return Promise.resolve(drawCard(ranIndex)).then((value) => dommy.innerHTML = (value[num]))
      };
      fill(1, "name")
      carda.classList.remove("default-styling");
      cardName.classList.remove("hide");
      moreInfo.classList.remove("hide")
    }
    setTimeout(500);
    cardb.addEventListener("click", changeCard("a"));
    setTimeout(500);
    carda.addEventListener("click", changeCard("b"));
```

```css
div.app_container {
  max-width: 600px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin: 15px auto;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-225deg, #e3fdf5 0%, #ffe6fa 100%);
  box-shadow: 8px 8px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.281);
  padding: 25px;
}
div.default-styling {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: #000000;
  background-color: aqua; /*Delete me!*/
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  max-width: 220px;
  padding-top: 125px;
  padding-bottom: 125px;
}

img.cardImg{
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 189px;
  height: 320px;
}
div.newCard, .carda, .cardb{
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 210px;
  border: none;
  background-color: red; /*Delete me!*/
  border-radius: 15px;
}
#cardb{
  float: right;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
.cardb{
  float: left;
  height: 320px;
  width: 300px;
}
h1 {
  font-family: "cursive";
  text-align: center;
}
h3,
p {
  font-family: "sans-serif";
  text-align: left;
}
small {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Daily Tarot</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png">
  <link rel="manifest" href="/site.webmanifest">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="app_container">
    <h1>Tarot</h1>
    <div id=c arda>
      <div class="carda default-styling">
        </br>
      </div>
      <div id=c ardb>
        <div class="cardb default-styling">
          </br>
        </div>
        <h3 class="name hide">Name of card</h3>
        <p class="about hide">About card</p>
        <h3 class="arcana hide">arcana card</h3>
        <p class="suit hide">suit card</p>
        <p class="fortune hide">Fortune telling</p>
        <p class="keywords hide"> keywords </p>
        <p class="meanings hide"> meanings </p>
        <p class="Archetype hide">Archetype </p>
        <p class="Hebrew hide">Hebrew Alphabet </p>
        <p class="Numerology hide">Numerology </p>
        <p class="Elemental hide">Elemental </p>
        <p class="Mythic hide">Mythical/Spiritual </p>
        <p class="Questions hide"> Questions to Ask </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <small>The images and information about each card are from
      <a href="https://www.tarot.com/tarot/cards">Tarot.com</a><br /><a
        href="https://github.com/SamJamWillingham/Tarot-Card-Drawer"
        >Open course code</a>
        </small>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

This particular question and its answer did not help:

[TypeError: Property 'handleEvent' is not callable IN FIREFOX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27384069/typeerror-property-handleevent-is-not-callable-in-firefox)

Thankyou and my apologies if I am doing this (code or posting) all wrong.

I was trying to get the card to change whenever the card on the page is clicked on through a DOM event. But what happens instead is "Uncaught TypeError: Property 'handleEvent' is not callable".

Comment: I would perhaps make a better question if you posted the related HMTL since it is DOM related. Suggest adding a snippet

Comment: I think the problem is `setTimeout(500)`. The first argument of `setTimeout` (which needs 2 arguments btw) should be a function, which 500 is not.

Comment: I edited and added your code to a snippet - however as posted it is malformed/incomplete and there was a weird `const cardDrawn- = ` which you can see from the edit history

Comment: Without fully formed code it appears you MIGHT be adding event listeners inside a async function which would normally not be a good thing to do and normally you don't add a parameter like this: `cardb.addEventListener("click", changeCard("a"));`

Comment: Rather that repeatedly loading the JSON inside `drawCard(x)` I would suggest you load it once and put it in an object and then do the random selection from that object.

Comment: Thankyou for all your help, I thought having the JSON loaded on startup may make it a little slow but I suppose I shall have to cope with what I can do.

The "setTimeout(500)" is just to make sure it wasn't something to do with things being called to quickly after the click event.